# From an ajax json request, how can dynamically add the objects to an array so that I can loop through them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

This is what I have so far, essentially I'd like to use the data to instantiate a new info-window from google maps api dynamically from the data response. I know so far that I'm pushing objects to an array(which are two different data types), but if that's the only wrong here. Then how can I dynamically add the response into an object so I can retrieve data with a loop?

```
    var i, venues, allVenues=[]; 
    $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'data'
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
    venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];
    JSON.parse(venues);
    for(i in venues){
    allVenues.push(venues[i]);
    }
   };
    /*Do something realistic with data other than logging it to console*/
    console.log(allVenues);
```

Comment: it depends on what is your return type from the function. If you are returning a pure json serialized data , then you would need to deserialize it to get an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it right, but not in the right place. jQuery.ajax will not wait for the response, but will invoke a 'success' callback when the request is answered.

Try this:

```
var i, venues, allVenues=[]; 
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'data'
  async: true,
  success: function(data) {
    venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];

    // The following line of code does nothing, because you
    // did not store it's return value. Fortunately it wasn't
    // even needed
    //
    // JSON.parse(venues);

    for(i in venues) {
      allVenues.push(venues[i]);
    }
    // or
    // allVenues.push.apply(allVenues, venues);
    // or in ES6
    // allVenues.push(...venues);
    // or the following will create a new array instance and save it in the allVenues variable
    // allVenues = allVenues.concat(venues);

    /*Do something realistic with data other than logging it to console*/
    console.log("Here are your updated venues:");
    console.log(allVenues);
  }
});
console.log("These are your old venues:");
console.log(allVenues);
```

EDIT:
You can check that the identity of the allVenues array didn't change by printing it to the console every second:

```
setInterval(function(stored) {
  console.log(stored);
  console.log(stored === allVenues);
}, 1000, allVenues);
```

EDIT:
To update an array to contain only the items of another array, you can use:

```
allVenues.length = 0;
allVenues.push.apply(allVenues, venues);
```

or

```
allVenues.length = venues.length;
for (var i in venues) {
  allVenues[i] = venues[i];
}
```

Comment: @tamas-hegedus What if I would like to use the very same array, just with updated information every time I made the reuqest? Instead of extending it, is that what array.push.apply() would do?

Comment: Yes, array.push.apply(array, ["a","b","c"]) is the same as array.push("a","b","c"), which is exactly what you want, and has the same effect as your for array pushing the elements one by one. In EcmaScript6 you will be able to write array.push(...newItems), where newItems is an array.

Comment: @tamas-hegedus, ok just to clarify every time the call is made, I've pushed the new venues into the array. Also at the same time old array items are gone now.      /*allVenues.push.apply(venues); */

Comment: Now I am not sure what is your goal. `allVenues.push.apply(venues);` is not correct, it should be `allVenues.push.apply(allVenues, venues);`, unfortunately this is how javascript works. I'm not passing the old array, because I want to retain it's items, I pass it to be the `this` pointer of the `push` call. (kind of disgusting). If you want to replace all the items in the array, you could simply clear the array before, see my edit